# iOS without Springboard: Terminating since there is no system event server

Tags: springboard

I'm attempting to create a simple ("Hello World") application using IB vs Springboard.
Once I added a button with its connection to an action routine, I get the following:

> Terminating since there is no system event server. (Run the EventPump
>   or pass the argument "-RegisterForSystemEvents" if you want to run
>   without SpringBoard.

Can someone please clarify this?

1) What's an 'EventPump' and how is it implemented?
2) Where do I pass the 'RegisterForSystemEvents'?

I searched through the Apple library & googled; but I haven't found any basic documentation on this.

Comment: Typo: "...using IB vs Springboard" should be '...using IB vs Storyboard"

Answer (score 18):

You're confusing SpringBoard and storyboards. Your storyboard is fine but you need to reboot your device (or Quit and restart the Simulator), as the SpringBoard (the process which handles the home screen) has died.

Answer (score 6):

Lee,
I was also facing same problem then i just close the simulator and reopen it.
it works fine for me next time.

Answer (score 3):

This won't answer your questions but might help people with the same issue.

What it worked for me was to delete the app in the iPhone simulator, force quit the simulator and hit run again in Xcode.

This happened when I switched a project from Xcode 4.5 Dev Preview to Xcode 4.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a use case scenario because Javawag's response helped me as well.

I ran into the same error message, and the problem was I was switching between two versions of xcode and two versions of the simulator.  I had the iOS 6 simulator running, switched to an older xcode that wanted the iOS 5 simulator, and got the odd error message mentioned.  I simply quit the iOS 6 simulator, allowed the older xcode to launch the correct simulator, and things worked again.

Answer (score 1):

quit simulator and run again.
If you have installed both XCode 4.5 and XCode 4.3.3 or older version, make sure that to quit both XCode and simulator to run on single version, i.e. eithere new or old. Simply it is because of using simulator (XCode 4.5) launching your application of older xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well when i switched between Xcode 4.5 and 4.2.1 . I just closed down the Xcode 4.5 and ran the project again. It worked.

Comment: "Turn it off and on again" advices are not really helpful. Please answer only if you have a profound solution to a problem.