# Why does my Monotouch App crash with iOS 6?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6

I need to make sure that our iPhone App (implemented with Monotouch) will still be be working from the very first day that iOS 6 is released to the public.

I've installed XCode 4.5 and iOS 6 Beta 3 and upgraded Monotouch to the latest version. Then I ran my app in the iOS 6 emulator and the app crashed instantly with the following error message:

Terminating since there is no system event server.
(Run the EventPump or pass the argument "-RegisterForSystemEvents" if you want to run without SpringBoard.

I've tried googling for similar problems but could not find anything. What can I do to make my App run on iOS 6?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Checkout this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301828/ios-without-springboard-terminating-since-there-is-no-system-event-server

Comment: @DataPriest: Thanks, but the problem is long solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details on iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5 are under NDA and won't be discussed publicly. Please either contact support@xamarin.com or fill **private** bug reports on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even if the circumstances are absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: its not really the answer though, it just cant be answered yet ;o)